# Sharing R markdown output

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am looking for a free, simple and privet solution to share reports generated with R markdown.
My goal is to be able to send a link to a colleague and he will be able to click it and go to the analysis.
Unfortunately I cannot use Rpubs for this as I cannot have the content public, nor do I want to pay for the Rstudio connect service as it is very expensive for me.

Any ideas will be welcome :)

Comment: Rmarkdown rendered to HTML will give you the entire file you need to send and they can view it in their web browser. Like stated in the answer if you use the `self contained` option, the html file will render with all the bytes it needs to contain everything within reasonable size.

Answer (score 1):

By default, RMarkdown rendered as HTML are [self-contained](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#document-dependencies). This means you can [compile the document into HTML file](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html) and simply email it to a colleague. It should have all that is needed to render the document on your colleague's web browser.

The only limitation is if your RMarkdown has any heavy interactive plots using Shiny, which would require a server and hosting website to run the application.

Otherwise, rendering your report as an HTML file and emailing it should be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason Rpubs is free, it is because it allows content to be shared. In the business model, everything is a tradeoff.

In that case you can use solutions like dropbox or google docs, and many others. It will not be something specific to R, but a generic solution. You just upload the content there and send him the link.

Be aware though that some of these tools create a long hash as the link to make for someone to guess it but, once it is shared, everyone who has the link can see it. It that case you might want to add authorization for access, so your colleague would have to have an account and log on to the tool in order to see it, so with each added requirement there will be more things to consider.